# What are the details of this struct inheriting from a template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In declarations, one can turn a c++ statement into words.

```
int a;  // a is declared an integer
```

I don't understand what the words are for the declaration below.

A is declared as a struct...?

```
struct A : public aTemplate<A> {};
```

I also don't understand how A can be used in two places.

Comment: TBH I don't have the slightest clue what you're asking about. Unless you're asking about the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: "I also don't understand how `A` can be used in two places." `A` is a type, so it would be like asking how can `int` appear in more than one place.

Comment: `struct A` says that `A` is the name of a `struct`; that makes it the name of a type. `aTemplate<A>` says to instantiate the template `aTemplate` with the type `A`, just as `aTemplate<int>` says to instantiate `aTemplate` with the type `int`.

Comment: its a struct called `A` that inherits from `aTemplate<A>`, ie a template called `aTemplate` instantiated for the template parameter `A`, ie the struct itself. Consider `struct node { node* left,right; }` as just another example, where the class of the name is "used in two places"